# Anything other than 'bar' chart breaks highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

**edit - I have narrowed it down to this line breaking it - pointFormat: '{series.name}: **{point.percentage:.1f}%**'
Any ideas why that would happen?

I used highcharts a few years ago and I'm just getting reacquainted. For some reason I can't get anything other than a pie chart working.

Using the basic bar example works fine:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('stats_container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});
</script>
```

But when I go to use any other example, like a pie chart:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('stats_container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2
    }]
}]
});
});
</script>
```

I get a http 500 error. I tried a highstock example too, and the same problem happened. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I can put in the series and other details for the pie chart, but it's when I start putting in the tooltip & plotoptions that it breaks. Thanks

Comment: In your code there's no petition to any server... If you're getting HTTP 500 it must be server related. Javascript does not cause error 500, an internal server error causes it.

Comment: Ok thanks @r1verside. It's really strange that one works and the other doesn't. Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I use smarty templates, and the js wasn't within a {literal} tag. Oooops